# Deploying fresh luya kickstarter-pack to fresh LAMP server

Tags: php, git, github, deployment

I am trying to deploy my fresh Kickstarter pack of LUYA CMS to LAMP server. I used a guide from the official site, but during deploy, state got an error. Here is my config:

```
// define your configuration here
server('prod', 'ip', 22)
    ->user('user')
    ->password('password') // You can use identity key, ssh config, or username/password to auth on the server.
    ->stage('prod')
    ->env('deploy_path', '/home/pi/luya/'); // Define the base path to deploy your project to.

set('repository', 'https://user:pass@github.com/user/luya.git');
```

Here is logs:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/dep luya prod -vvv
➤ Executing task deploy:prepare
↳ on [prod]
> echo $0
< bash
< 
> if [ ! -d /home/pi/luya/ ]; then mkdir -p /home/pi/luya/; fi
> if [ ! -L /home/pi/luya//current ] && [ -d /home/pi/luya//current ]; then echo true; fi
> cd /home/pi/luya/ && if [ ! -d releases ]; then mkdir releases; fi
> cd /home/pi/luya/ && if [ ! -d shared ]; then mkdir shared; fi
• done on [prod]
✔ Ok [917ms]
➤ Executing task deploy:release
↳ on [prod]
> if [ -d /home/pi/luya//releases/20190418193704 ]; then echo 'true'; fi
> mkdir /home/pi/luya//releases/20190418193704
> cd /home/pi/luya/ && if [ -h release ]; then rm release; fi
> ln -s /home/pi/luya//releases/20190418193704 /home/pi/luya//release
• done on [prod]
✔ Ok [273ms]
➤ Executing task deploy:update_code
↳ on [prod]
> which git

In PhpSecLib.php line 124:

  [RuntimeException]
```

Exception trace:
     () at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Server\Remote\PhpSecLib.php:124
     Deployer\Server\Remote\PhpSecLib->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\functions.php:296
     run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\recipe\common.php:54
     {closure}() at n/a:n/a
     call_user_func() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Server\Environment.php:101
     Deployer\Server\Environment->get() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\functions.php:573
     env() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\recipe\common.php:176
     {closure}() at n/a:n/a
     call_user_func() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Task\Task.php:79
     Deployer\Task\Task->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Executor\SeriesExecutor.php:43
     Deployer\Executor\SeriesExecutor->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Console\TaskCommand.php:82
     Deployer\Console\TaskCommand->execute() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
     Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:960
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:255
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:148
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\src\Deployer.php:101
     Deployer\Deployer->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\l.site1.com\luya-kickstarter\vendor\deployer\deployer\bin\dep:64

```
luya [-p|--parallel]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Git is not installed on this Server. In order to run LUYA deployer, the GIT command must be available.